# Bmcweb sensors cannot be shown successfully

Tags: openbmc

I want to ask how to show the sensors reading in bmcweb with webui-vue.

After tracing the code and from openbmc doc, I thought webui-vue is getting the sensor reading information from redfish and seems like I have to completed file "association.json".

But I have no idea how to refer from meta-ibm's association.json file due to I don't have its machine structure.

I have completed hwmon system, so I can see all my sensors data in `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmonXXX`.

And I can request the data from dbus like `busctl introspect xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-607868621.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/PDB_Temp`.

I also registered the sensor reading data to ipmi like below.

[ipmitool sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF2Ha.png)

So, I think the reading data is on d-bus correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to put your sensor data to Redfish:

1. [phosphor-hwmon](https://github.com/openbmc/phosphor-hwmon) + [phosphor-inventory-manager](https://github.com/openbmc/phosphor-inventory-manager)

From your service name it looks like you already use `phosphor-hwmon`, so to push the sensor data to Redfish you will need something like this:
https://gerrit.openbmc.org/c/openbmc/meta-amd/+/38320

2. [dbus-sensors](https://github.com/openbmc/dbus-sensors) + [entity-manager](https://github.com/openbmc/entity-manager)

This is a more modern solution. For the example please look at the:
https://gerrit.openbmc.org/c/openbmc/openbmc/+/42415