# openbmc + ast2500 web display sensors failed (hwmon seems ok)

Tags: web, yocto, dbus, openbmc

I am a newbie no matter from openBmc or ast2500.

After a huge amount of try and errors and browse lots of discussions and docs, right now my ast2500 seems could booting successfully with **webui-vue** through NCSI network.

And already confirm that hwmon interfaces and conf of my desired sensors are working ( tmp464 and ADCs), and busctl also has showed the objects.

Below are related testings for references.

**- (1) busctl tree <service>**

```
root@ast2500-default:\~# busctl -l --full |grep hwmon
:1.41                                                                                             356 phosphor-hwmon- root             :1.41         xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon@-ahb-apb-bus\\x401e78a000-i2c\\x2dbus\\x40300-tmp468\\x4048.service -       -
:1.60                                                                                             381 hwmontempsensor root             :1.60         xyz.openbmc_project.hwmontempsensor.service                                               -       -
xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1 356 phosphor-hwmon- root             :1.41         xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon@-ahb-apb-bus\\x401e78a000-i2c\\x2dbus\\x40300-tmp468\\x4048.service -       -
xyz.openbmc_project.HwmonTempSensor                                                               381 hwmontempsensor root             :1.60         xyz.openbmc_project.hwmontempsensor.service                                               -       -
```

```
root@ast2500-default:\~# busctl -l --full |grep hwmon
:1.41                                                                                             356 phosphor-hwmon- root             :1.41         xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon@-ahb-apb-bus\\x401e78a000-i2c\\x2dbus\\x40300-tmp468\\x4048.service -       -
:1.60                                                                                             381 hwmontempsensor root             :1.60         xyz.openbmc_project.hwmontempsensor.service                                               -       -
xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1 356 phosphor-hwmon- root             :1.41         xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon@-ahb-apb-bus\\x401e78a000-i2c\\x2dbus\\x40300-tmp468\\x4048.service -       -
xyz.openbmc_project.HwmonTempSensor                                                               381 hwmontempsensor root             :1.60         xyz.openbmc_project.hwmontempsensor.service                                               -       -
```

**- (2) busctl introspect <service> <path>**

```
root@ast2500-default:/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0# busctl introspect xyz.openbmc_project.ADCSensor /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE  RESULT/VALUE  FLAGS
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -          -             -
.Introspect                         method    -          s             -
org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager  interface -          -             -
.GetManagedObjects                  method    -          a{oa{sa{sv}}} -
.InterfacesAdded                    signal    oa{sa{sv}} -             -
.InterfacesRemoved                  signal    oas        -             -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer           interface -          -             -
.GetMachineId                       method    -          s             -
.Ping                               method    -          -             -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -          -             -
.Get                                method    ss         v             -
.GetAll                             method    s          a{sv}         -
.Set                                method    ssv        -             -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as   -             -

root@ast2500-default:/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0# busctl introspect xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/outlet
NAME                                                  TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE FLAGS
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable                   interface -         -            -
.Introspect                                           method    -         s            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer                             interface -         -            -
.GetMachineId                                         method    -         s            -
.Ping                                                 method    -         -            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties                       interface -         -            -
.Get                                                  method    ss        v            -
.GetAll                                               method    s         a{sv}        -
.Set                                                  method    ssv       -            -
.PropertiesChanged                                    signal    sa{sv}as  -            -
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Threshold.Critical         interface -         -            -
.CriticalAlarmHigh                                    property  b         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalAlarmLow                                     property  b         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalHigh                                         property  d         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalLow                                          property  d         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalHighAlarmAsserted                            signal    d         -            -
.CriticalHighAlarmDeasserted                          signal    d         -            -
.CriticalLowAlarmAsserted                             signal    d         -            -
.CriticalLowAlarmDeasserted                           signal    d         -            -
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Threshold.Warning          interface -         -            -
.WarningAlarmHigh                                     property  b         -            emits-change writable
.WarningAlarmLow                                      property  b         -            emits-change writable
.WarningHigh                                          property  d         -            emits-change writable
.WarningLow                                           property  d         -            emits-change writable
.WarningHighAlarmAsserted                             signal    d         -            -
.WarningHighAlarmDeasserted                           signal    d         -            -
.WarningLowAlarmAsserted                              signal    d         -            -
.WarningLowAlarmDeasserted                            signal    d         -            -
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value                      interface -         -            -
.MaxValue                                             property  d         -            emits-change writable
.MinValue                                             property  d         -            emits-change writable
.Unit                                                 property  s         -            emits-change writable
.Value                                                property  d         -            emits-change writable
xyz.openbmc_project.State.Decorator.OperationalStatus interface -         -            -
.Functional                                           property  b         -            emits-change writable
```

Getting value from dbus

```
busctl tree xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1
`-/xyz
  `-/xyz/openbmc_project
    `-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors
      `-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature
        `-/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/outlet
root@ast2500-default:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2# busctl introspect xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/outlet
NAME                                                  TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE FLAGS
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable                   interface -         -            -
.Introspect                                           method    -         s            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer                             interface -         -            -
.GetMachineId                                         method    -         s            -
.Ping                                                 method    -         -            -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties                       interface -         -            -
.Get                                                  method    ss        v            -
.GetAll                                               method    s         a{sv}        -
.Set                                                  method    ssv       -            -
.PropertiesChanged                                    signal    sa{sv}as  -            -
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Threshold.Critical         interface -         -            -
.CriticalAlarmHigh                                    property  b         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalAlarmLow                                     property  b         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalHigh                                         property  d         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalLow                                          property  d         -            emits-change writable
.CriticalHighAlarmAsserted                            signal    d         -            -
.CriticalHighAlarmDeasserted                          signal    d         -            -
.CriticalLowAlarmAsserted                             signal    d         -            -
.CriticalLowAlarmDeasserted                           signal    d         -            -
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Threshold.Warning          interface -         -            -
.WarningAlarmHigh                                     property  b         -            emits-change writable
.WarningAlarmLow                                      property  b         -            emits-change writable
.WarningHigh                                          property  d         -            emits-change writable
.WarningLow                                           property  d         -            emits-change writable
.WarningHighAlarmAsserted                             signal    d         -            -
.WarningHighAlarmDeasserted                           signal    d         -            -
.WarningLowAlarmAsserted                              signal    d         -            -
.WarningLowAlarmDeasserted                            signal    d         -            -
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value                      interface -         -            -
.MaxValue                                             property  d         -            emits-change writable
.MinValue                                             property  d         -            emits-change writable
.Unit                                                 property  s         -            emits-change writable
.Value                                                property  d         -            emits-change writable
xyz.openbmc_project.State.Decorator.OperationalStatus interface -         -            -
.Functional                                           property  b         -            emits-change writable

//busctl get-property <service> <obj> <interface> <property>
busctl get-property xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/outlet xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value Value
d 57


root@ast2500-default:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2# busctl get-property xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-ee3d03a1f22c872c2068069ed5a7f03963bd0a5cd43c66214114d45e29f01fbb.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/outlet xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value Value
d 56
```

==
(Option 1)
I found something seems likely related to my problem from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652571/bmcweb-sensors-cannot-be-shown-successfully](https://stackoverflow.com), which mentioned two methods:

**(1) phosphor-hwmon + phosphor-inventory-manager ( my case )**
**(2) dbus-sensors + entity-manager**

And the method 1 seems related to configuration folder.

```
xxxx@Debian-11:~/aspeedTech/openbmc/meta-aspeed-sdk/recipes-phosphor/configuration$ ls
ast2500-yaml-config  ast2500-yaml-config.bb
```

**(Option2)**
Directly copy meta-ibm/meta-romulus/recipes-phorsphor/inventory/ to my layer

Preview of this layer

```
xxx@Debian-11:~/aspeedTech/openbmc/meta-aspeed-sdk/recipes-phosphor/inventory$ ls

inventory-cleanup  inventory-cleanup.bb  phosphor-inventory-manager_%.bbappend
```

--

But after patching into my project separately above options, still the webUI has nothing display on it, wondering what is the next step I could do......

[webui-vue display sensors with nothing snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI0FB.png)

By the way, my source code info are:

**(1) my code base if from AspeedTech repository**

**(2) Layer at meta-aspeed-sdk**

**(3) setup using 'ast2500-default'**

**(4) using webui-vue**

**(5) current use layer (the sensors folder default not provided by Aspeed, I reference and modified from meta-romulus)

```
xxx@Debian-11:~/aspeedTech/openbmc/meta-aspeed-sdk/recipes-phosphor$ ls

configuration  dbus  flash  initrdscripts  interfaces  inventory  ipmi  leds  network  packagegroups  pmci  sensors  settings  usb  webui
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references I got from openBMC's discord community.
Put here for notes and I will try to work on it!

(Ref 1)
Mspinler:

If you're using phosphor-hwmon, you'll need to manually create associations so bmcweb can find them.  https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/architecture/sensor-architecture.md#redfish  says which ones.  phosphor-inventory-manager has a JSON file you can put them in, see https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/architecture/sensor-architecture.md#redfish.  if you look for associations.json files in openbmc/openbmc you'll see examples

(Ref 2)
Troy Lee :

You already populate the sensor on d-bus, then you're almost there.
https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/architecture/sensor-architecture.md#redfish